# Can I fetch more than 100 fans from facebook page?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

using the fan.php API I can extract info about max 100 likers (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=150495894979290) , if I use connection with higher value I get "Param connections must be a number less than or equal to 100" error

how can I get this information for connection > 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link.

[Get Facebook Page Likes all at once in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401365/get-facebook-page-likes-all-at-once-in-c-sharp)

Since facebook prevents this list to be accessed to discourage selling fans data to 3rd party companies. As far as I know you can get a maximum of only 100 persons using this..Sorry