# Get Facebook Page Likes all at once in c#

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to get all fans basic data who likes my Facebook page. I have post a request to this URL(https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=XXXXXXXXX) and i am getting response as 100 fans at a time randomly. I need all the fans at once or else 100 unique members at a time but not random. Is there any chance to get all 53k fans at a time. Can we use Graph API for this. Please help me.
Thanks,
Neer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way you can access the list of your 53,000 fans through Graph API (neither via FQL).

Facebook prevents this list to be accessed to discourage selling fans data to 3rd party companies (and as a subtle way to prevent competition of targeted ads).

However, with the Like button plugin endpoint URL (https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=XXXXXX) you can parse the HTML and saving the new ones appearing there, iterating a call to the endpoint every X seconds. Just be careful as this is really not allowed on Facebook TOS and you can be banned (or even get a legal complaint) by implementing that.

Cheers!